# Implementing Antilogarithm[b, x] and Cologarithm[b, x]

Tags: functions

*Mathematica* functions for `antilogarithm[b, x]` and  `cologarithm[b, x]`   don't appear to exist, but I think they could be implemented. I searched the site, but I didn't find what I want. Please give me advice.

Comment: Look up the definitions if you don't know them, build the functions.

Answer (score 3):

The following antilogarithm function works: `antiLog[b_: E, z_] := b^z` .

Then the base can be changed via `b` & since the default for `Log` is `E`, `antiLog[Log[x]]` produces `x`.  However, as GuessWhoItIs pointed out in the comments, `Power[~]` is worth looking into first.  `Power[~]` is actually exactly equivalent to this.

Similarly, your own cologarithm function can be written such that

`coLog[b_: E, z_] := Log[b, 1/z]`.

Comment: Short version: in *Mathematica*, the antilogarithm is implemented as `Power[]`. :)

Comment: You forgot to add the base in `coLog[]`. On the real line, the simpler version is `-Log[b, z]`, but things are different for complex arguments.

Comment: Ah thank you, @Guesswhoitis.

Comment: In light of Guesswhoitis first comment, why not `antiLog = Power;` ?

Comment: Oh @m_goldberg, yes it does.  I'll edit accordingly.  I hadn't actually checked yet to see if they were identical.  Thank you.

Comment: thanks , with that I can implement what I need

Comment: @Fernando you may want to accept this answer officially by clicking the grey check mark next to it.